# Homeo-Fixed point property

Tags: gn.general-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds, fixed-point-theorems

**Edit:** According to comment of   Michał Kukieła I revised the  question

A topological  space $X$ satisfies "Homeo-fixed point"  property if every  homeomorphism $f$ on $X$ possess a  fixed point.

> Is there  an example of  a  connected  manifold with this  property but does  not  satisfies  fixed point  property?

**Edit** Now i found a related paper, so I add the link to this question:

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02771655

Comment: Notation: FPP = fixed point property. Disjoint union of a manifold with FPP and a manifold without FPP does not have FPP, but it has FPP with respect to homeomorphisms. So you probably want to assume your manifold is connected.

Comment: @MichałKukieła  thank you for the interesting comment. however I prefer to  consider connected manifold, but your example is very interesting

Comment: What if one connect the two spaces X and Y of Michał Kukieła's example by an arc (say with some more convenient assumption)?

Comment: @PietroMajer  I would appreciate if you more explain.

Comment: E.g. a topological space $P$ homeomorphic to the letter "P". Every homeo $P\to P$ has at least 2 fixed points, while  a continuous map $P\to P$ may have none. ($P$ is not a topological manifold of course)

Comment: @PietroMajer thanks  for your  Very interesting Idea. This  is  a  motivation to  ask: what  about $\mathbb{C}P^{2}\# \mathbb{T}^{4}$  as  a  manifold?( The  Connected sum)

Comment: In your question you refer to two properties.  But I only see one property defined.  To me your question reads: is there an example of something with property X but does not satisfy property X.

Comment: @RyanBudney: "Is there an example of something with property X but not with property FPP?" In other words, is there a connected topological space (or even manifold) such that each homeomorphism has fixed point but not every continuous mapping has fixed point?

Comment: @VítTuček: where is the property regarding continuous functions mentioned?

Comment: I suppose the fixed point property could also refer to $C^{r}$-maps on $C^{r}$-manifolds.

Comment: @RyanBudney I just offered my interpretation of the question, whose wording can (and should) certainly be improved. I'm a topological outsider (ehm) and my understanding is that FPP is a standard term which means that all continuous mappings of the space to itself have a fixed point. Since homeomorphism is a special case of a continuous mapping it makes sense to ask for which spaces all homeorphisms have a fixed point whereas some continuous mappings don't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

consider the connected sum of the klein bottle with the projective plane

there is a map with no fixed point
collapse to the klein bottle and rotate

any homeo induces a map on mod two homology which is an isomorphism
 respecting the intersection form

i didn't calculate but if the trace mod two of any such 3x3 matrix is non zero then
any homeomorphism has a fixed point

in any case this is an idea to construct an example

Dennis Sullivan

Answer (score 2):

Let me construct a non-paracompact counterexample. Of course, a paracompact counterexample is better in many respects since differential topology is usually restricted to paracompact manifolds and because the manifolds that naturally occur and the ones sold [here](http://www.kleinbottle.com/) are all paracompact.

Let $L=([0,1)\times\omega_{1})\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ be the long line. Let $M$ be any paracompact manifold with the fixed point property for homeomorphisms. For instance, $M$ could be a projective space over the reals, the complex numbers, or over the quaternions.
Let $N=L\times M$.

I claim that $N$ has the fixed point property for homeomorphisms but not for continuous maps.

Clearly, there is a retraction $f:N\rightarrow S$ where $S\simeq M\times(0,1]$. The set $M\times(0,1]$ does not have the fixed point property since the map $M\times(0,1]\rightarrow M\times(0,1],(x,y)\mapsto(x,y/2)$ has no fixed point. Therefore there is some map $g:S\rightarrow S$ without a fixed point. Thus $g\circ f:N\rightarrow S$ has no fixed point.

Now assume that $h:N\rightarrow N$ is a homeomorphism.

If $x\in M$, then let $\Gamma_{x}:L\rightarrow L,\Delta_{x}:L\rightarrow L$ be the maps where $\Gamma_{x}(y)=\pi_{1}(h(y,x)),\Delta_{x}(y)=\pi_{1}(h(y,x))$. Let
$C_{x}=\{\alpha\in\omega_{1}|\Gamma_{x}(\alpha,0)=(\alpha,0)\},D_{x}=
\{\alpha\in\omega_{1}|\Delta_{x}(\alpha,0)=(\alpha,0)\}.$

I claim that the sets $C_{x},D_{x}$ are club sets (club stands for closed unbounded). It is clear that the sets $C_{x},D_{x}$ are closed, so we now need to show $C_{x},D_{x}$ are unbounded.

It is easy to see that for all $\alpha\in\omega_{1}$, we have $\Gamma_{x}(z)>(0,\alpha)$ for sufficiently large $z$. Therefore, for all $\alpha\in\omega_{1}$ there is a sequence $(y_{n})_{n}$ with $(0,\alpha)<y_{0}$ and where $y_{n}<y_{n+1},y_{n}<\Gamma_{x}(y_{n+1}),\Gamma_{x}(y_{n})<y_{n+1},\Gamma_{x}(y_{n})<y_{n+1}$. Furthermore, one can choose the sequence $(y_{n})_{n}$ so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_{n}=(0,\gamma)$ for some $\gamma$. Therefore, we have $\Gamma_{x}(0,\gamma)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Gamma_{x}(y_{n})=(0,\gamma)$. We conclude that $\gamma\in C_{x}$, so $C_{x}$ is unbounded. Thus $C_{x}$ is a club set. The set $D_{x}$ is a club set as well by an identical argument.

Let $A\subseteq M$ be a countable dense subset. Then let $E=\bigcap_{x\in X}C_{x}\cap D_{x}$. Then $E$ is a club set being the countable intersection of club sets.

Now assume that $\alpha\in E$. Then since $(\alpha,0)=\Delta_{x}(\alpha,0)=\pi_{1}(h((\alpha,0),x)$ for $x\in X$, we have
$h[\{(\alpha,0)\}\times X]\subseteq\{(\alpha,0)\}\times M$. Therefore, we have
$h[\{(\alpha,0)\}\times M]=h[\overline{\{(\alpha,0)\}\times X}]\subseteq\{(\alpha,0)\}\times M$. Similarly, we have $h^{-1}[\{(\alpha,0)\}\times M]\subseteq\{(\alpha,0)\}\times M$. Therefore, $\{(\alpha,0)\}\times M\subseteq h[\{(\alpha,0)\}\times M]$. We conclude that
$h[\{(\alpha,0)\}\times M]=\{(\alpha,0)\}\times M$.

However, since $M$ has the fixed point property for homeomorphisms, and $h[\{(\alpha,0)\}\times M]=\{(\alpha,0)\}\times M$, the mapping $h$ has some fixed point on $\{(\alpha,0)\}\times M$.